# django setting foreign key (one to zero-or-one)

Tags: django, entity-relationship

I want to setting foreign key as below image.
[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXJJs.png)

my current code:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    file_id = models.OneToOneField('A', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```

thanks.

Comment: why don't you use OneToOneField instead? you can do with `blank=True`

Comment: @Beomi I don't want to be possible that make B without A. 'blank=True' it can do that? I am noob in Django.

Comment: what do you wanna make exactly? if you want like post - attachedFile, You can do like this: ForeignKey(A), and if you do not have to add B object for A. But you can't add B without A.

Comment: @Beomi Although I forgot to mention about 'non-nullable field is need to set a default value', I could solved my problem. thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reference the class (instead of passing a string value).

```
file_id = models.OneToOneField(A, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
```